# difference between rdd.collect().toMap to rdd.collectAsMap()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

Is there any performance impact when I use collectAsMap on my RDD instead of rdd.collect().toMap ?

I have a key value rdd and I want to convert to HashMap as far I know collect() is not efficient on large data sets as it runs on driver can I use collectAsMap instead is there any performance impact ?

Original:

```scala
val QuoteHashMap=QuoteRDD.collect().toMap 
val QuoteRDDData=QuoteHashMap.values.toSeq 
val QuoteRDDSet=sc.parallelize(QuoteRDDData.map(x => x.toString.replace("(","").replace(")",""))) 
QuoteRDDSet.saveAsTextFile(Quotepath)
```

Change:

```
val QuoteHashMap=QuoteRDD.collectAsMap() 
val QuoteRDDData=QuoteHashMap.values.toSeq 
val QuoteRDDSet=sc.parallelize(QuoteRDDData.map(x => x.toString.replace("(","").replace(")",""))) 
QuoteRDDSet.saveAsTextFile(Quotepath)
```

Comment: There is no significant performance difference. `collectAsMap` simply collects `RDD` and creates a mutable `HashMap` on a driver.

Comment: is there a way to create hashmap using best practice ? without using collectAsMap or collect().toMap ?

Comment: If you expect duplicate keys you can reduce amount of data transfered to driver by removing duplicates first otherwise it is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation of `collectAsMap` is the following

```scala
def collectAsMap(): Map[K, V] = self.withScope {
    val data = self.collect()
    val map = new mutable.HashMap[K, V]
    map.sizeHint(data.length)
    data.foreach { pair => map.put(pair._1, pair._2) }
    map
  }
```

Thus, there is no performance difference between `collect` and `collectAsMap`, because `collectAsMap` calls under the hood also `collect`.

Answer (score 2):

No difference. Avoid using collect() as much as you can as it destroys the concept of parallelism and collects the data on the driver.