# efficient way to create a hash map using RDD as input in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a source file which is converted to `RDD` and this `RDD` is later converted to hashmap using `toMap` function but the function uses collect which is very slow.

My data set is about 1Million records .

My Code:

```
RDD.collect().toMap.values.toSeq
```

Is there any effiencet way of doing this converting a `RDD` to `HashMap` without using collect ?

Thanks
Sri

Comment: The closets you can get in case you have a PairRDD is a rdd.collectAsMap() that returns a Map[K, V] to the master.

Comment: @eliasah [The function `collectAsMap()` just runs `collect()` under the hood and iterates over each pair to place into a map.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233175/difference-between-rdd-collect-tomap-to-rdd-collectasmap/33233504) So there isn't really a difference :-/

Comment: @RohanAletty I know. I'm just not very sure what the OP wants.

Comment: How are you partitioning things? 1 million records isn't very many, if they're not individually enormous. Just run everything on one node, possibly not even using Spark.

Comment: Have you considered mapping to rrd of just the values and then collecting it? This may be marginally faster

Comment: To be honest it's 1 billion records , I used 50 as my partition as my nodes in my cluster are just 15 so as of my knowledge (data bricks ) partition should be number of nodes * 2 , so my code for partition is like this rdd=sc.textfile(file,50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, efficient is a relative term but if you don't mind shuffling then a distributed equivalent of your code is simply something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val pairRDD: RDD[(T, U)] = ??? // Some RDD of Tuple2[T, U]
val mapLikeRDD = pairRDD.reduceByKey((_, v) => v)
```

If all you want is values just follow above with:

```
mapLikeRDD.values
```

On a side note `mapLikeRDD` is pretty much a textbook hash table. Not particularly efficient though, since expected number of collisions is high so I wouldn't abuse `lookup` method.